# google visualization type mismatch

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, datetime, google-visualization

using google visualization i get Unix Epoch timestamps and try to convert it to array of string. I try to use string for google charts, but get an error

```
Type mismatch. Value 2017-8-25 16:23:54,2017-8-25 16:11:54,... does not match type string in column index 0
```

My code looks like this:

```
 var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "JSONurl",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (dataJson) {
    var mass = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {
        //console.log(data[i].dateExecutes.toString());
        var dateEx = new Date(dataJson[i].dateExecutes);
        var year = dateEx.getFullYear();
        var month = dateEx.getMonth()+1;
        var day = dateEx.getDate();
        var hours = dateEx.getHours();
        var mins = dateEx.getMinutes();
        var secs = dateEx.getSeconds();
        var newDate = (year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs);
        mass[i] = newDate;
    }
    //console.log(mass);
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //var date1 = new Date(jsonData.dateExecutes);
    //var date2 = date1.toGMTString();
    //alert(jsonData.dateExecutes);
    data.addColumn('string', mass);
    data.addColumn('number', 'passed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'failed');
    //data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'tooltip', id: 'testRunId'});
    dataJson.forEach(function (row) {
            data.addRow([
            mass,
            row.passed,
            row.failed
        ])
    });
```

How do i use array in Column? How to build cell from array?
please, any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not exactly clear on what you're trying to accomplish

if you just want a formatted date string as the first column,
recommend using google's `DateFormat` class

no need for two loops, the date can be formatted directly in the `forEach` statement

see following snippet...

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
  url: "JSONurl",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (dataJson) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'passed');
  data.addColumn('number', 'failed');

  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
  });

  dataJson.forEach(function (row) {
    var rowDate = new Date(row.dateExecutes);
    data.addRow([
      formatDate.formatValue(rowDate),
      row.passed,
      row.failed
    ]);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm actually find solution myself, but your way looks much easier. But your method doesn't show correct time, for example:
2017-8-25 18:35:56 
is shown as:
2017-8-25 06:35:56
how to fix hours?

Comment: alright, i have fixed it myself. just changed hh for HH in formatDate pattern.